# MIN date from within GROUP

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to work out if the following is possible within a single query.

We have the following Query that gets information from Tables A and B

```
SELECT 
     a.wj_job
     ,a.wj_sched
     ,a.wj_lump
     ,SUM(b.wj_billed) AS wj_billed
     ,SUM(b.wj_received) AS wj_recd
     ,a.wj_lbdate
     ,a.wj_fecom1 
FROM ag_fsch a
     JOIN ag_fschd b ON a.wj_job = b.wj_jbnum AND a.wj_sched = b.wj_sched 
WHERE 
     a.wj_job LIKE "4733.%"
GROUP BY 
     a.wj_job
     ,a.wj_sched 
ORDER BY 
     a.wj_job
     ,a.wj_sched
```

I would like to extract the last unpaid bill date from table b as part of the above Query. The same thing can be achieved by the query below, but only for a specific result in the original Query.

```
SELECT 
     MIN(wj_bdate) 
FROM ag_fschd
WHERE 
     wj_jbnum = 4733.00
     AND wj_sched = 6
     AND wj_billed <> 0
     AND wj_received = 0
```

Comment: The second query `min` will give you 1 record only. Do you want to display the same record for all the rows of first query?

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.  (Newer MySQL versions follow this rule, older doesn't.)

Comment: jarlh is right; your query doesn't look proper. What are the tables' unique keys?

Comment: Table A has a UNIQUE index on wj_job and wj_sched. Table B has a UNIQUE index on wj_job, wj_sched, wj_bdate and wj_crno. Unfortunately these are 3rd party tables that we need to report on

Comment: @Utsav We would want to return a different MIN(date) for each schedule a job has. In the example the Job has 7 results coming from Table A (7 schedules). Each schedule can have multiple entries in table B (with unique dates)

Comment: @DanKelly - Some sample data for both the tables and your expected output would be good to understand the question better

Comment: Okay, if  `wj_job` plus `wj_sched` are unique, but `wj_jbnum` plus `wj_sched` are not, then your query selects `wj_job`, `wj_lbdate`, and `wj_fecom1` arbitrarily per group, as you don't use aggregate functions to specify which you want to get per group. This is something to be aware of when using MySQL.

Comment: Just realised that there there a.wj_jbnum should have been a.wj_job later in the pasted query. ag_fsch (table a) only has one entry per Job/Schedule. Hence this will only ever have one wj_lbdate and one wj_fecom1. It is the table B columns that we are aggregating (or in this case getting the MIN date from)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use conditional aggregation.  I'm not sure because there are two keys in the `group by`, not just the job number.  But, this may be the output you want:

```
SELECT a.wj_job, a.wj_sched, a.wj_lump, SUM(b.wj_billed) AS wj_billed,
       SUM(b.wj_received) AS wj_recd, a.wj_lbdate, a.wj_fecom1,
       MIN(CASE WHEN b.wj_sched = 6 AND b.wj_billed <> 0 AND b.wj_received = 0
                THEN wj_bdate
           END)
FROM ag_fsch a JOIN
     ag_fschd b
     ON a.wj_jbnum = b.wj_jbnum AND a.wj_sched = b.wj_sched 
WHERE a.wj_jbnum LIKE '4733.%'
GROUP BY a.wj_jbnum, a.wj_sched 
ORDER BY a.wj_jbnum, a.wj_sched;
```

Comment: Apart from dropping the b.wj_sched from the CASE this appears to produce the results that we are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Using a sub query to get the min date for each one:-

```
SELECT a.wj_job, 
        a.wj_sched, 
        a.wj_lump, 
        SUM(b.wj_billed) AS wj_billed,
        SUM(b.wj_received) AS wj_recd, 
        a.wj_lbdate, 
        a.wj_fecom1 ,
        sub0.wj_bdate
FROM ag_fsch a
JOIN ag_fschd b ON a.wj_jbnum = b.wj_jbnum AND a.wj_sched = b.wj_sched 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT wj_jbnum,
            wj_sched,
            MIN(wj_bdate) 
    FROM ag_fschd
    WHERE wj_billed <> 0
    AND wj_received = 0
    GROUP BY wj_jbnum,
            wj_sched
) sub0
ON sub0.wj_jbnum = a.wj_jbnum AND sub0.wj_sched = a.wj_sched
WHERE a.wj_jbnum LIKE "4733.%"
GROUP BY a.wj_jbnum, a.wj_sched 
ORDER BY a.wj_jbnum, a.wj_sched
```

Note as Jarlh pointed out in the comments, the GROUP BY clause is a bit odd as it doesn't have all the non aggregate fields in it. I have made no attempt to fix that here.